# images disappers when i tried using homepage in pakage.json in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, apache, tomcat, react-router, react-hooks

i wanted to deploy my reactjs app on tom cat server.what i did is
1.Added homepage in pakage.json
2.added basename in reactrouter
3.ran npm run build.
then copied the files na dput in web app folder of apache tomcat.
all works well but the only thing that is not working is routing and images disappears.i tried various methods but was not able to solve it

and for loading images purpose what i have done in public folder i have created images folder and i amfetching images by src='/images/image_name.png' it was working very well but after using homepage in the package json the images disappears..seems having issue with the path

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bunge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://localhost:8080/simpleapp2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is my react route in the app.js

```
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import UserProfile from './components/main/UserProfile';
function App() {
  return (
    
      <div className="grid-container">
        <BrowserRouter  basename={'/simpleapp2'}>
        <header>
          <Header/>
        </header>
        <main >
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/userprofile" component={UserProfile}/>
          </Switch>
      
        </main>
        <footer>
          <Footer/>
        </footer>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

and i am images purpose what i have done in public folder i have created images folder and i fetching images by src='/images/image_name.png' it was working very well but after using homepage in the package json the images disappears..seems have issue with the path

Comment: Remove `homepage` key

Comment: then in apache server the page dont work.means its shows page not found

Comment: You have given homepage of localhost

Comment: yes i have given homepage of localhost,i followed one blog and was able to run in apache server by adding homepage but images disappears then after